# Renaming an OpenOffice Calc sheet

Tags: c#, openoffice-calc

I have created a program that reads in from a number of different files and stores different information in OpenOffice Calc. The following code I have used to create a spreadsheet sheet:

```cs
public XSpreadsheet getSpreadsheet(int nIndex, XComponent xComp)
{
    // Collection of sheets
    XSpreadsheets xSheets = ((XSpreadsheetDocument)xComp).getSheets();
    XIndexAccess xSheetsIA = (XIndexAccess)xSheets;
    XSpreadsheet xSheet =(XSpreadsheet)xSheetsIA.getByIndex(nIndex).Value;

    return xSheet;
}
```

This method is called as follows:

```cs
XSpreadsheet newSheet = getSpreadsheet(sheetIndex, xComp);
```

I know how to enter data in the table etc. however I don't know how to rename the sheets for an OpenOffice application. Looking through the internet I have only managed to find information for Excel application that doesn't work for OO.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this is possible?

Comment: Which api are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never programmed to OpenOffice, so I assume you're using [this api](http://www.openoffice.org/api/). At the docs, I found that [XSpreadsheet](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/Spreadsheet.html) implements [`XNamed`](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/container/XNamed.html), which exports the methods `setName` and `getName`. That seems to be what you want. If I'm mistaken, tell me -- as I've said, I've never used this.

Comment: Thank you that really helped, I managed to get the following code to work: 'XNamed xPageName = (XNamed)(xSheet);
                                 xPageName.setName("Content");'Thanks again